# How can I  perform sleep() or wait() in Corona?

Tags: coronasdk

I want to pause the application for 500 msec. How can I do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `timer.performWithDelay()` for it.

Comment: `timer.perfomWithDelay()` schedules a specified function call after a defined delay, therefore it not behaves exactly like as `wait()` or `sleep()`, since if sequence execution exists it will continues running, . To use as a `wait()` is necessary to adapt the code for each case.

Answer (score 1):

```
-- Sleeps for x milliseconds
function usleep(nMilliseconds)
    local nStartTime = system.getTimer()
    local nEndTime = nStartTime + nMilliseconds

    while true do 
        if system.getTimer() >= nEndTime then
            break
        end
    end
 end
```

That would work :)

Comment: This will freeze the app.